# oracle, with function clause, possible to use more than one function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run more than one function in the WITH clause using oracle 12c.

Trying to accomplish the following

```
WITH
   FUNCTION 1
   FUNCTION 2
SELECT
function1(variable)
function2(variable)
FROM
wherever;
```

Is this possible? I've tried directly, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Intresting, I can run 2 stored procs with 12g

Comment: Yes it's possible as Husqvik's answer shows.  If it doesn't work for you it might be a problem with an older client or IDE.  The new WITH syntax is a bit different and will not work in some IDEs.  Before that 12c syntax, a SQL statement would never have a semicolon inside it, and many tools would automatically assume that the first semicolon was the end of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It absolutely is:

```
HUSQVIK@hq_pdb_tcp> WITH
  2     FUNCTION function1(p VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
  3     BEGIN
  4         RETURN 1;
  5     END;
  6     FUNCTION function2(p VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
  7     BEGIN
  8         RETURN 2;
  9     END;
 10  SELECT
 11     function1(dummy) result1,
 12     function2(dummy) result2
 13  FROM
 14     dual;
 15  /

   RESULT1    RESULT2
---------- ----------
         1          2

1 row selected.
```